# What will happen after downloading OTA in to android device

Tags: android-source, ota

I got to know how to OTA checking the new version , downloading the file.

I am queries about to know, how OTA is working after downloading the OTA firmware in device(indetail) level.
I have check in google and I got overall how OTA working in top level.But I could not find in-depth.
If you have any links or documents please share to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a some description of the OTA upgrade process available in the 
SystemUpdaterSample [README.md](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample/README.md) file. You might have to look at the source codeof that sample app for further details.